# having problems with pointers and scanf?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

In the code, I encountered the problem of entering the address for `scanf` in the Check Array function when running and failed to enter the value and it ended the program immediately.
How can I fix it?

**Code:**

```
bool CheckArray(int** arr, int index)
{
    fflush(stdin);
    char temp;
    printf("\ntest0 \n");
    if (scanf("%d%c", &(arr)[index], &temp) == 2) { // input
        printf("\ntest 1 \n");
        if (temp == '\n')
            printf("\ntest 2 \n");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void addValue(int** arr, int& size)
{
    fflush(stdin);
    size++;
    arr = (int**)realloc(arr, (size) * sizeof(int*));
    printf("Input number to array:");
    while (!CheckArray(arr, size - 1)) {
        printf("Invaild a value: ");
    };
    //scanf("%d",arr+(size-1));
    printf("Number of array: %d", arr[size - 1]);
}

bool CheckMenu(int& number, int min, int max)
{
    fflush(stdin);
    char temp;
    printf("Input menu:\n");
    if (scanf("%d%c", &number, &temp) == 2) {
        if ((temp == '\n') && ((number >= min) && (number <= max)))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
void menu(int** arr, int& size)
{ // menu of programing
    int number;
    while (true) {
        if (number == 6)
            break;
        printf("----Chuong Trinh----\n");
        printf("1. Add a value\n");
        printf("2. Search a value\n");
        printf("3. Print out array \n");
        printf("4. Print out values in range inputted min and max values, inclusively\n");
        printf("5. Sort the array in ascending order\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n\n");
        while (!CheckMenu(number, 1, 6)) {
            printf("invail \n");
        }
        switch (number) {
        case 1:
            addValue(arr, size);
            break;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    int* arr;
    arr = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int)); // malloc memory
    menu(&arr, size); // menu
    free(arr); // free the memory
    return 0; // return
}
```

Comment: Is this `C` or `C++`? You are using `references` in function argument and you tagged this question under `C` tag.

Comment: There are several problems not one in your code: in `main()~ you are allocating `0 bytes` to `arr` and then you are using it. In `menu()`, there's a mismatch of data types when you are calling `addValue(arr, size);` and then I didn't see rest of the code.

Comment: I increased the value by 1 but it still fails, ```addValue(arr, size);``` add & whenever the three pointers but it still fails

Comment: Don't `fflush(stdin);` ever.